# Primefaces dnd in datatable with jboss 7.1

Tags: primefaces, jboss7.x, drag-and-drop

I tried to implement an example of Primefaces dnd using jboss 7.1 and PF 3.5.14 but it doesn't work. I tried with the exactly same code but ...

Do i need the last version of JSF? I think that JBoss 7.1 does not have it.

Here is the code: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dndTable.jsf

Best regards

Comment: The primefaces showcase run on PrimeFaces-4.0-SNAPSHOT have you try with this ?

You can find this [here](http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/primefaces/4.0-SNAPSHOT/primefaces-4.0-20130828.122054-5.jar).

Comment: No. Not yet. I saw that there were Problems and Classes not found. Is it new this Drag n Drop with datatable?

Comment: I tried with PF 4.0 RC1 and it still does not work. :( any other idea?

Comment: Nobody has an idea? Primefaces released pf3.15 but it also does not work. Anybody already implemented drag and drope with datatables?

Comment: I debuged with Firebug and noticed that my Fieldset soen't have the (style)class "ui-droppable". That's the problem but... WHY?

Answer (score 1):

I now know why i didn't work. I have a template in my xhtml page. The javascript method used by primefaces

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function handleDrop(event, ui) {
            var droppedLineItem = ui.draggable;

            droppedLineItem.fadeOut('fast');
        }
    </script>
```

is in my page but the javascript function was not loaded in my template.

I simply added:

```
<ui:insert name="head"></ui:insert>
```

in my template page and it worked!